# Why is Susy giving my columns a 44.44444% width instead of 50%?

Tags: css, sass, css-float, compass-sass, susy-compass

Cannot figure out why my columns are not 50% when no-gutters is included in the parameters?

SCSS:

```
$susy: (
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  gutters: 1/4,
  gutter-position: before
);

.columns {
  @include clearfix;
}

.column {   
  .twoColumns & {
    @include span (1 of 2 no-gutters);
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.columns:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.twoColumns .column {
  width: 44.44444%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set gutter-position with inside value to get 50% of columns:

```
$susy: (
  global-box-sizing: border-box,
  gutters: 1/4,
  gutter-position: inside
);

.columns {
  @include clearfix;
}

.column {   
  .twoColumns & {
    @include span (1 of 2 no-gutters);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you actually don't want gutters, you can also just change the setting to `0` or `null`.